# Ruby undefined method

Tags: ruby

I am doing a ruby exercise, when I run this script, first it said "26.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end", so I added " end" in the last line. then it said "26.rb:77:in `<module:Ex25>': undefined method`secret_formula' for Ex25:Module (NoMethodError)". I think the function secret_formula is fine?

thanks!!

```
module Ex25

  # This function will break up words for us.
  def Ex25.break_words(stuff)
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
  end

  # Sorts the words.
  def Ex25.sort_words(words)
    return words.sort
  end

  # Prints the first word after popping it off.
  def Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    word = words.pop(1)
    puts word
  end

  # Prints the last word after popping it off.
  def Ex25.print_last_word(words)
    word = words.pop
    puts word
  end

  # Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words.
  def Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    return Ex25.sort_words(words)
  ed

  # Prints the first and last words of the sentence.
  def Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end

  # Sorts the words then prints the first and last one.
  def Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
    words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    Ex25.print_fist_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end
end


puts "Let's practice everything."
puts 'You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

poem = <<END
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
END

puts "--------------"
puts poem
puts "--------------"


five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
puts "This should be five: #{five}"

def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
  return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

puts "With a starting point of\: #{start_point}"
puts "We'd have #{beans} beans, #{jars} jars, and #{crates} crates."

start_point = start_point / 10

sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
sorted_words = Ex25.sort_words(words)
Ex25.print_first_word(wrds)
Ex25.print_last_word(words)
Ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
Ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
sorted_words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)

END
```

Comment: if this is just copy/pasted you have a mispelled `end` in the `Ex25.sort_sentence` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get a syntax error, the first thing to do is tell Ruby to interpret the file with maximum warnings. I saved the code to "test.rb" and let Ruby look at it:

```
>ruby -cwW2 ~/Desktop/test.rb
warning: statement not reached
warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 27
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

In this case,

```
warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 27
```

points to the method in the code that isn't terminated correctly.

Sometimes the interpreter is very confused and can't give you a specific line, but in general this is the best starting point.

Here are the flag definitions:

```
-c              check syntax only
-w              turn warnings on for your script
-W[level=2]     set warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose
```

Comment: thanks so much the Tin Man for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a mispelled "end" in this method:

```
def Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
  words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
  return Ex25.sort_words(words)
ed
```

Comment: thanks jkeuhlen and grenierm5...I was looking at it many times, but just missed it.